# Android - unable to uninstall application

Tags: android, uninstallation

I have some Android market feedback for my app `Hire*A*Droid` where users complain that they are unable to uninstall the application. Here's two I have so far (about 10 days apart):

```
janelle: I uninstalled this app, but its still showing that its 
         installed under my downloads. What can i do ?
valerie: It's frozen I can't open or delete it. 
         anyone can help n tell me how..thanks
```

The app has nothing really special or tricky about it and I never experienced anything of the sort so I'm really lost at what this may be, how real it is and how to reproduce and deal with it? Any ideas, suggestions? If you have any questions that you think may help with this problem I'll be happy to provide more details

P.S. Worth nothing to mention - both complaints cost me a single star rating and no additional info was provided

P.P.S. After comment from PHP Jedi I noticed similar comments for other apps while browsing Android Market. I think this is quite common and it looks like Market bug. I will try to open a bug on Android Market support site

[Cross-referenced](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android+Market/thread?tid=026b76b7c8f3d90a&hl=en) to Android Market forum

Comment: How can you tell something is installed under your downloads?  That just seems weird to me.

Comment: I think she is referring to "Downloads" list under Android market which shows app that are installed on the phone

Comment: I got similar feedback that some cant uninstall our app. So yes, i'm curios about finding a good answer here. Thanks for making the question, you are not alone with this "problem"

Comment: Where oh where are Google gurus when you need them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from what i understand (i don't work on Market myself), the "Downloads" list inside Market can be out of date for up to a day, until it next gets an update from the server. the app isn't actually installed anymore, and Settings > Applications > Manage Applications will show that it is indeed gone.

i reported this as a Market bug internally last year. i've just added a link to this page from that bug, and i'll try to get someone to look at it.

(it may even already be fixed in newer versions. it would be interesting to know the most recent version you've seen it in.)

Comment: I build and distribute "Top Job Search" using 1.5 and the evidence is vague indeed but as I mentioned I do stumble on similar comments in other apps

Comment: Elliott - can you please provide link back to the bug here?

Comment: no, it's in Google's internal bug database, not the public "android issues" one. i'll try to talk to someone on the Market team today to see if this is already fixed in later versions of Android.

Answer (score 3):

I purchased a DROID a week back and was having the same problem.  To uninstall an application from the DROID do the following.

Uninstalling an application from Android OS v2.1

1. Go to settings.
2. Go to Applications
3. Go to Manage applications.
4. Touch the application you wish to uninstall.
5. Touch uninstall.
6. Enjoy the fact that the application is gone.

The confusion I'm guessing your commenter's are having is when you hold your finger on an application you can drag it to a trash bin.  This makes you think you are deleting the application when really you are removing it from your favorite applications list.  Its very misleading.

Comment: I'm not convinced since 1- the app is not installed by default onto the desktop, 2 - user #2 specifically complains that app is "frozen I cannot open or delete it". There are generally 2 ways of uninstalling the app the one you described and also from the market when you select the application.
Of course the ease with which sloppy user can leave you one star feedback and never bother check it back is really maddening but that's a different story

Comment: In response to your first statement consider this.  When under the main menu if you hold your finger down on an application after a few seconds a trash barrel appears making you think you can delete it.  Really what is happening is you are adding it to the desktop.  When you drag it to the barrel nothing happens.

Comment: "When you drag it to the barrel nothing happens." I have the same problem with my Samsung Admire (2.3.4). I consider it a bug.  Thank you for the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

I could not say why the users complain, but I could say that your application work without problem on my HTC Magic, I don't get error when I tried to uninstall it.

Best Regards

Comment: Thank you. I do understand that it is an anomaly rather than rule. And it may be that @GrandPrix is right and it is misunderstanding on the part of some users